# Android widget different portrait and landscape orientation

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, screen-orientation

I have a (hopefully) a relatively simple question. How do I tell Android which layout to use for portrait and which layout to use for landscape orientation on my AppWidget?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, bear in mind that some home screens (e.g., Nexus One) do not change orientation.

The standard approach for having different layouts per orientation is to put the portrait version in `res/layout/`, and the landscape version in `res/layout-land/`, both under the same name (e.g., `appwidget.xml`). Then, just refer to it by name (e.g., `R.layout.appwidget`), and Android will choose the file based on the orientation. This definitely works for activities, so I would assume it works for app widgets, but I don't think I have actually tried it.

Comment: I thought he was talking about the appwidget provider XML file where you state you minWidth & minHeight. From what your saying would you declare another provider in xml-land?

Comment: Confirmed my own question. You can give two providers one in layout and one in layout land, they will only be called IF the appwidget is created when in that orientation, they won't be called on an orientation change

Answer (score 2):

To change the width and height of the app widget, define two different `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` sizes for your layout (in the `res/layout-port` and `res/layout-land`). Then define the **larger** width and height in your `appwidgetinfo.xml`. That way, the app widget changes size when the orientation is changed and not just when you add the widget to the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RemoteViews to dynamically update your widget you can supply two separate RemoteViews to the updateAppWidget function call. For example:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews rvLandscape=new Remoteviews(context,R.layout.widget_landscape);
    rvLandscape.addView(...
    :

    RemoteViews rvPortrait =new Remoteviews(context, R.layout.widget_portrait);
    rvPortrait.addView(...
    :

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, new RemoteViews(rvLandscape, rvPortrait));
}
```